# Dock the Task List peek to the corner in Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016.  With my current layout, I can view the Task List using a "peek" at the bottom of the folder list navigation.  I'd like to be able to dock the Task List in roughly that location (green box in the following diagram):

[image: Outlook screenshot]

However when I "dock peek", the only place it will dock is down the right-hand side of the screen (red box in the diagram).  Is there a way I can dock it in the corner so as not waste screen real estate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is by design and can't be changed. If you would still like to achieve this , it is suggested to share your feedback via the [Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows).